# Using JSON object value from url in Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

What I'm doing (or trying to do) is retrieve a JSON object from a URL then deserialize it, and using the Selenium "By.X" values put that in my code instead of hard coding it in.

Code:

```
dynamic theJsonDecoded = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
var test = theJsonDecoded.template.login_url.ToString();
//Helpers.returnMessage(theJsonDecoded.template.login_username_field.ToString());
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(theJsonDecoded.template.login_url.ToString());
IWebElement user = driver.FindElement(theJsonDecoded.template.login_username_field.ToString());
user.SendKeys("xxxxxx@xxx.com");
IWebElement pass = driver.FindElement(theJsonDecoded.template.login_password_field.ToString());
pass.SendKeys("xxxxxx");
IWebElement loginButton = driver.FindElement(theJsonDecoded.template.login_button.ToString());
loginButton.SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Enter);
Thread.Sleep(3000);
driver.Quit();
```

Everything is coming back from the URL fine, i can output the needed sections of the JSON, but i'm getting the error:

> OpenQA.Selenium.IWebDriver' does not contain a definition for 'FindElement'

This:

```
IWebElement user = driver.FindElement(theJsonDecoded.template.login_username_field.ToString());
user.SendKeys("xxxxxx@xxx.com");
```

Would be this, if it was hardcoded in:

```
IWebElement user = driver.FindElement(By.Id("user_email")
user.SendKeys("xxxxxx@xxx.com");
```

When I hard coded it in, it worked great. I'm not sure what the issue could be, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It is missing parameter 'By' in the findElement of your code.

***by*** - The locating mechanism to use for WebDriver's FindElement method.

[Refer FindElement - documentation](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#findElement-org.openqa.selenium.By-)

Correct way is:

```
IWebElement user = driver.FindElement(By.id(theJsonDecoded.template.login_username_field.ToString()));
```

Comment: The 'By.Id' element is actually here: theJsonDecoded.template.login_username_field.ToString()); taken from the JSON, but it still fails, but if i hard code it, it works for some reason.

Comment: So in the JSON this would be an example: "login_username_field":"By.Id(\"user_email\")" it might not always be By.Id that's why i kept from hard coding that part.

Comment: FindElement(by class) actually work with object, you are providing a string, will be a miracle if works :)

Comment: Well, in that case you need to parse your json string to two parts, one is for Locator type [By.Id] and other one is for locator identifier ["user_email"].

Comment: @graham23s `driver.FindElement(By.Id("user_email"))` is not the same as `driver.FindElement("By.Id(\"user_email\")")`. `.FindElement()` doesn't take a `string`, it takes a `By` locator. That's what you have wrong. You really shouldn't be storing locators in JSON anyway... store them in your code and you can avoid issues like this.